# how to persist only string data in webix, can we use webix.storage.local.put?

Tags: webix

I would like to store string value at exit stage & retrieve it in application open stage. I am unable to store data directly by using webix.storage.local.put()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unload event to store the data

```
webix.attachEvent("unload", function(){
  webix.storage.local.put('t1-val', $$('t1').getValue() );
})
```

Check the next sample

http://webix.com/snippet/eceb4da2